# Naming worksheets once an SSRS report is exported into Excel

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a single report which includes several tablixes. Once the report is run, it is exported into Excel by the team using it.

For each tablix I clicked into its properties and ticked **Add a page break after**

doing this ensures that when the report is exported to Excel each tablix's data appears on a separate worksheet.

However when the export takes place the worksheets are named 'sheet 1', 'sheet 2' etc

Ideally I'd like the separate worksheets in Excel to reflect the name of the tablix, e.g. 'last week', 'this week' etc etc. Or to be able to name the worksheets myself.

Is anyone aware of a way this can be done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have gotten this to work by placing the tablix into a rectangle, which has a "Page Name" option in the general settings section, this is what's used to create the exported worksheet name in Excel.