# Visual Studio 2017 - Multiple Excel Worksheets

Tags: excel, reporting-services, visual-studio-2017

I am looking to make a three worksheet excel workbook to be pulled off of our SSRS page. In Visual Studio 2017 I have my three datasources with their tables in the 'design' but want to have three worksheets. Currently it is pulling them all in one which makes sense as currently built. Does anyone know how to leverage Visual Studio to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put each tablix into a rectangle shape and amend the page name accordingly, as per
[Naming worksheets once an SSRS report is exported into Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52366939/naming-worksheets-once-an-ssrs-report-is-exported-into-excel/52368325#52368325)

Comment: I was able to get it using "PageBreak", "PageName" however I used for naming the sheets. Thanks Again!